# how put div center when use float

Tags: html, css

there is one div with width 100% inside it is another div with float left how can put it in center ? i try use margin 0 auto but its not work

http://jsfiddle.net/cterh0sv/

```css
.test {
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    background:green;
}

.inside {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:white;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove float, set `text-align: center` to container and `display: inline-block` to items.

```css
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
}
.inside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="inside">
  </div>
  <div class="inside">
  </div>
  <div class="inside">
  </div>
</div>
```